# Рассчитать центр и масштаб карты

Tags: javascript

> В интерфейсе есть карта на весь экран и на ней 2 точки (lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2). Необходимо рассчитать координаты центра карты (lonC, latC) и масштаб - количество метров карты на определенное количество пикселей на экране (scale), так чтобы обе точки были на экране на максимальном расстоянии друг от друга но с отступом от края карты 50px.

Как решить эту задачу?

Comment: Обязательно рассчитывать координаты центра и масштаб?
Может проще взять координаты 50px от края карты?

Comment: как - выяснить, чем отличаются географические координаты (широта и долгота) от декартовых координат в проекциях карт

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, то примерно вот так:

```
var lonC=lon1/2+lon2/2;
var latC=lat1/2+lat2/2;
var scaleX=(screenWidth-leftOffset-rightOffset)*(lon2-lon1);//Pixels in meter x
var scaleY=(screenHeight-topOffset-bottomOffset)*(lat2-lat1);//Pixels in meter y

var scale;//Scale equals minimal scale between scaleX and scaleY
if(scaleX<scaleY)
    scale=scaleX;
else scale=scaleY;
```